# Create a class member function that allows to set class members

Tags: typescript

I want to create a class that has a `set()` function like this

```ts
set(key: string, value: any) {
  this[key] = value;
  return this;
}
```

This would allow me to chain my calls.

The issue I'm facing is that the `key` parameter can take any value, whereas I would like it to take only the value of the class members I have defined.

For instance:

```ts
export class Person {
  public age: number;
  public name: string;

  // User can set 'age' or 'name', but can't set 'height'
  public set(key: string, value: any) {
    this[key] = value;
    return this;
  }
}
```

I know I can use a type such as:

```ts
export type ofPerson = 'age' | 'name';
```

But that would imply that I hard-code every key of my class. It's OK with `Person`, but my actual class has more members than that...

Is there a way to type the parameter to follow the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `keyof`  operator

```
interface IPerson {
   age: number;
   name: string;
}

class Person implements IPerson {

   public age: number;
   public name: string;

   public set(key: keyof IPerson, value: any) {
     this[key] = value;
     return this;
   }
}

const person = new Person();
person.set() // allows only properties defined in `IPerson`
```

Example with interface in the [**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Person%20implements%20IPerson%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%2F%2F%20User%20can%20set%20'age'%20or%20'name'%2C%20but%20can't%20set%20'height'%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20set(key%3A%20keyof%20IPerson%2C%20value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20person%20%3D%20new%20Person()%3B%0D%0Aperson.set()).

Comment: Simple and efficient, thank you ! is there a way to ignore getters with this ?

Comment: `keyof` gets all properties which are defined in this type. As a workaround you can create an interface with this properties and use `keyof` with that interface. I have updated the answer with the example

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that would avoid using strings for keys is using object as value setter :

```
export class Person {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;

    set(values: Person): Person {
     return Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

This way you could call the setter with n parameters :

```
person = person.set({age: 15});
person = person.set({age: 45, name: 'SpongeBob'});
```

If you want to mutate the current object :

```
export class Person {
    name ?  : string;
    age ?  : number;

    set(values: Person): Person {
        for (let key of Object.keys(values)) {
            this[key] = values[key];
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
person.set({age: 15});
person.set({age: 45, name: 'SpongeBob'});
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the getter error (`readonly property`), and I need to have required class members. But although it's not adapted to my case, it is a good point, so +1 !

Comment: (Also, personal preference, but I prefer to chain `.set` calls rather than using only one)